# React: How I can change a state variable based on the value of another state variable?

Tags: reactjs

Sorry if I am asking something really stupid, I am new to React and there is probably some very basic concept I am still missing.

Can someone explain to me how I can change a state variable based on the value of another state variable?

This is what I tried, but I can't get it to work:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0)
  const [id, setId] = useState(0)

  function handleSubmit() {
    setNumber(10)
    changeId()
  }

  function changeId() {
    setId(number)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Change number</button>
      <h1>{number}</h1>
      <h1>{id}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Before that, I tried this more direct approach, which of course, also failed:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0)
  const [id, setId] = useState(0)

  function handleSubmit() {
    setNumber(10)
    setId(number)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Change number</button>
      <h1>{number}</h1>
      <h1>{id}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In your case** Just keep it as simple as below

```
function App() {

  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0)
  const id = number

  function handleSubmit() {
    setNumber(10)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Change number</button>
      <h1>{number}</h1>
      <h1>{id}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

- by clicking button we set the number to 10 and then the function App will execute from the beginning and `id` gets the new value

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wai6tf)

---

but if you have complex logic to handle when the value of  `number` getting change you need `useMemo` hook

```
const id = useMemo(() => {
    return number;
}, [number])
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wuedcg?file=index.js)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, it definitely helps. However, now one of the two variables stopped being a state variable. Does that mean that it is not possible to keep them both as state?

Comment: If one state variable is depend on other state, then you dont need to put both as state variables it will hard to maintain